# Is it appropriate to forefeit the right to accept an answer in the future if a bounty expires?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounties

> **Related:**
>   [bounty questions -no answers after bounty has started- what happens ? [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38282/bounty-questions-no-answers-after-bounty-has-started-what-happens-closed)

Per the FAQ:

> If there is no answer meeting the above criteria, and you as the question owner have not opted to accept an answer, you forfeit your right to ever accept an answer to your question.

I have [a very niche question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568624/how-do-i-get-folder-size-with-exchange-web-services-2010-managed-api) about a topic that (based on the number of views and answers) I assume very few people are currently doing.

I am considering adding a bounty to encourage more views, but I am worried that I may still have 0 answers when the bounty period expires. If, a year from now, more people are using EWS2010, and someone posts an answer to my question, I would have no ability to accept their answer. That bothers me.

I suppose I could, at that point, repost the question, and repost the answer myself for the sake of documentation, linking to the original with an explanation of why I've done it, but then I'm just getting rep for myself, not for the person who solved the problem; and cluttering the database with duplicate data.

Is it just known and accepted that if this situation arises, that the votes will be "good enough" to indicate the best answer to the problem?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/should-so-introduce-a-re-bounty-feature if you'd like to support a suggestion to allow people to bounty questions more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

This is effectively completed, because

- bounty system is no longer tied to accepting an answer in any way
- you can issue multiple bounties on your question if necessary

Answer (score 0):

People are smart.  If the first answer doesn't solve their problem (when they find your question via google) then they go to the next answer, even if they've never seen or used SO before.

So yes, every answer matters.  "Accepted" and sort by vote are merely aids in getting to the best answer faster, but they don't stall the process even if out of order.

> Is it appropriate to forfeit the right to accept an answer in the future if a bounty expires?

Yes.  It helps to prevent certain types of rep gaming.