# Why were no answers auto-accepted when the bounty period ended?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, bounties, auto-acceptance

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649733/hide-cursor-on-remote-terminal/2676973#2676973) had a bounty created on it, and the bounty period ended today.  I expected to see an accepted answer, but there is none.  **Why did the system not auto-accept the top voted answer?**

I read the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow) to try to understand this.  It says that in the event of a bounty period ending, when the question owner does not accept an answer, then the top-voted answer will be automatically accepted -- as long as the answer is +2 or more, and that answer was created after the bounty was started.

I believe my answer met both of those qualifications.

(The only thing I could think of, is that I edited this question's tags.  Could that disqualify me from having my answer accepted?)

Is this a bug?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/is-it-appropriate-to-forefeit-the-right-to-accept-an-answer-in-the-future-if-a-bo

Comment: When was the bounty started on that question?

Comment: April 20, ~9:00AM Eastern Time

Comment: @ChrisF When the bounty ended, there had been three answers given.  Mine was at +2, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Is it possible the 2nd upvote came after the bounty expired?

Comment: He has +20 Rep from that question as early as the 23rd, [according to his graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/125389?tab=reputationhistory). I can't see the vote counts, but it doesn't look like he had any downvotes that would counter it.

Comment: No, my answer was +2 a few days ago.

Comment: Was your answer entered *prior* to the bounty being set?

Comment: No.  It was entered during the bounty.

Comment: That is bizarre. It looks like the bounty was entered on 4/20, which coincides with the date of your answer. (See rep graph: http://stackoverflow.com/users/58657?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody added some "security" to our scheduled tasks, which caused them not to run on SO.

Fixed.

Comment: Somebody? Security?

Comment: It was this guy: http://xkcd.com/278/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we 'regular' users of the system don't have enough insight into the dates that each event occurred to prove or disprove it.

From our perspective:

- The bounty and your answer was made on the same day (but time could have been an issue)
- You did receive at least two upvotes between the 20th and the 26th

So the only hard issue is whether the bounty was set prior to your answer or not, and since we don't have a time stamp on the bounty (something I wish showed up in the timeline!) then we can't confirm hours/minutes.

Comment: The bounty's timestamp is available to diamond moderators, I hear.  Perhaps I should flag my question as needing moderator attention! :-)

Comment: please vote for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history